# Fine area of hexagon traced by cevians of trisecting points of triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, fractions, ratio

In any triangle ABC, two points are marked on each side, in order to divide the side into three equal parts. When tracing the cevians to each of the six marked points there will be a hexagon in the center of the figure. Give the ratio between the area of ​​the hexagon and the area of ​​the triangle ABC.

Comment: Could you please, at least, include a sketch of that?

Comment: My hint is: the ratio is the same as it would be if the triangle were equilateral.  (There exists an affine transformation that maps any triangle into an equilateral triangle.  Affine maps preserve area ratios.)

Comment: I rolled the edit back to the original version (with one minor change--fixing a typo).  The revision by @MicahWindsor seems to be different from what the OP intended to say.  I however decided not to clarify what I think the OP means, because I am not too certain that my interpretation is correct either.  The OP should attach a drawing to make sure people understand correctly, or reword the question.

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304882/morley-theorem-variant-trisecting-a-triangles-sides-instead-of-its-angles – also, http://www.gogeometry.com/problem/p122_marion_walter_theorem_proof_area.htm

Comment: Here's a nice reference: https://girlsangle.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/marion-walters-theorem-via-mass-points/ – also, http://www2.edc.org/makingmath/mathprojects/marionwalter/links/marionwalter_lnk_1.asp and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarionsTheorem.html and probably others.

Comment: Had a look at any of those links, Tass?

Comment: Yes! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

Let [] denote areas. For the trisecting points D, E and F on the respective sides of the triangle ABC, it is well-known that

$$[XYZ] = \frac17[ABC]$$

It can also be shown that

$$\frac{XU}{XZ} = \frac14,\>\>\>\>\>\frac{XV}{XY} = \frac25$$

As a result,

$$[XVU] = \frac14\cdot\frac25 [XYZ] = \frac1{10}[XYZ]$$

Similarly,
$$[YTS] = [ZWH] =\frac1{10}[XYZ]$$

Thus, the area of the hexagon is

$$[UVSTHW] = [XYZ] - [XVU] - [YTS] - [ZWH] $$
$$= (1-\frac3{10})[XYZ]=\frac7{10}[XYZ]=\frac1{10}[ABC]$$

Thus,  the are ratio between ​​the hexagon and the triangle ABC is $\frac1{10}$.

Comment: Doesn't a cevian go from a **vertex** to a point on the opposite side? Shouldn't the cevians be AE, AQ, BF, BR, CD, and CP?

Comment: Please, show the ratios that you used, because I can't see them.